# Cannot mock class: Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException

Tags: laravel, phpunit, mockery

I try to run a phpunit test for my Laravel 6.0 application, but when trying to mock a method, I get this message as it cannot find the class/method:

> Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method scrapeGoogleData() from Mockery_2_App_Http_Controllers_Scraper should be
>   called  exactly 1 times but called 0 times.

My test code is:

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Http\Controllers\Scraper;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class ScrapeTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /** @test */
    public function test_scrapeGoogleData() {
        $this->mock(Scraper::class, function ($mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('scrapeGoogleData')->once();
        });
        Scraper::scrape('www.google.com');
    }
```

The "scrapeGoogleData" method is definitely ran as it's called from the `Scraper::scrape` method. But for some reason, mockery cannot see that. I get this error:

> Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method scrapeGoogleData() from Mockery_2_App_Http_Controllers_Scraper should be
>   called  exactly 1 times but called 0 times.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're mocking the whole class, so the code in your scrape method is not run. You'll have to make a partial mock, to keep any method which is not explicitly mocked.

EDIT:

You'll have to resolve it from the container and then call scrape on that:

```
app(Scrape::class)->scrape('www.google.com');
```

Comment: Adding $mock->makePartial() doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Can you post the body of your scrape method? Also if it's not a public method you should use `shouldAllowMockingProtectedMethods()`

Comment: It's something like:
class Scraper {

    public static function scrapeGoogleData($region, $keyword, $retries = 6) {
        $url = self::getGoogleURL($region, $keyword);
...
        return ($http_code == 200) ? $content : FALSE;
     }
}

Comment: Oh I know what's going on. You're statically calling the `scrape` method. So you're basically never using the mock. You'll have to resolve it from the container and then call scrape on that: `app(Scrape::class)->scrape('www.google.com')`